# Is there a way to show nothing when a sharepoint library view is empty?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint Online page that shows a document library in different views.

When a view is empty, Sharepoint shows a large icon and a text to copy files to this location. This takes a lot of space and I don't want users to copy files to the view.

Is there any way to show nothing when the view is empty and to hide the icon?

Answer (score 0):

You may deploy the SPFx extension to your tenant so you could inject CSS to OOB list view(global).

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/react-application-injectcss/README.md

Or create your own SPFx extension so you could limit to specific view.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension